# My time whter in between Start time and End Time

Tags: java, android, date, time

This logic doesn't work if the current time is 18.
   Here Start time is 22(10pm) and End Time 06(6am)
   Thanks in advance.

```
int hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if (hour > 22) {
        if (hour > 06) {
            return true;

        }
    }

    if (hour < 22) {
        if (hour < 06) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (hour == 00) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: I had function called NightMode , I ll set start and end time. So in that time all connectivity will diable , So need boolean value to check wther current time is in between start and end..Thanks Rajesh For u reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is far to localized to a specific case, but you need:

```
if (endHour < startHour) { // the end is on the next day
    if (hour > startHour || hour < endHour) {
        return HOUR_IS_IN_RANGE;
    }
}
else { // end hour is on the same day as start shour
    if (hour >startHour && hour < endHour) {
        return HOUR_IS_IN_RANGE;
    }
 }
 return HOUR_NOT_IN_RANGE;
```

You should also consider >=/<= instead of just > and <.